# Virtualbox: normal start fails, headless/detached start runs

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, headless

When I try to start my newly created virtual machine on a fresh install of Virtualbox I get the following message.

> *Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Debain. The virtual machine 'Debian' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit
>   code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in
>   'C:\Users\me\VirtualBox VMs\Debian\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.*
>
> *Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005) 
>
>   Component: MachineWrap 
>
>   Interface: IMachine { ... somecode }*

I tried the following things

- Disable guest network adapter
- Adding all Virtualbox processes to the windows firewall exception
- Removing my antivirus
- Reinstalling Virtualbox (with and without cleaning my registry in between)
- Changing the system type of the guest
- Booting with / without the Debian iso installer
- Starting with every possible combination in the Virtualbox guest settings
- [Edit] Checking out my XML file; http://bit.ly/2aPfWmt

Finally, starting the VM in *Headless* or *Detachable* Start makes it work just fine. I can then *Show* the VM without a problem. Debian is installing right now. I can even switch to scaled or fullscreen modes without a problem (had errors with previous versions of Virtualbox)

I have the following information for you

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Intel i7 3630QM + 8GB RAM
- nVidia GeForce 680M + Intel HD 4000 (nVidia Optimus)
- Virtualbox 5.1.2 r108956
- VT-d is enabled in BIOS

This pretty much sounds like a bug in Virtualbox, but I have not been able to find anyone else reporting this. Does anyone have any theories about what may be going on? How is the regular start different from the Headless/Detachable, even though the GUI works after the VM has started?

Comment: you may need to fix xml file http://bit.ly/2aPfWmt

Comment: I also found this but forgot to add it to my tried list. My Debian.xml is in the right place and looks just fine. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, when I was in windows 10 it worked fine for me but when I install win7 then my VM not starting in normal mode. what is the fix for it?

Comment: I eventually solved it by trying different (older) versions of Virtualbox

Comment: Experiencing similar problem.  Seems to be the most recent version of Virtualbox.  Likely should go as a bug report to Oracle rather than StackExchange.